# Adapter Pattern for more than one object

Tags: object, adapter, software-design

Adapter is a wrapper that convert an interface to another interface. The common example of adapter I know is the adapter wrap only single object, but could it possible that adapter wrap more than one object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A adapter pattern is not to *wrap* an interface! The Adapter pattern, as the name implies, adapts the interface of one class to match the interface expected by another class.

Typical usage is adapting a SQL interface to a ActiveRecord pattern.

In general you can adapt to multiple flavors of a Interface, by swapping to another adaper, based on a common class.